# I am trying to run XGBoost in R but am facing some issues

Tags: r, xgboost

I have a dataset of 25 variables and 248 rows.
There are 8-factor variables and the rest are integers and numbers.
I am trying to run XGBoost.
I have done the following code: -

```
# Partition Data
     set.seed(1234)
     ind <- sample(2, nrow(mission), replace = T, prob = c(0.7,0.3))
     train <- mission[ind == 1,]
     test <- mission[ind == 2,]

   # Create matrix - One-Hot Encoding for Factor variables
     trainm <- sparse.model.matrix(GRL ~ .-1, data = train)
     head(trainm)
     train_label <- train[,"GRL"]
     train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(trainm), label = train_label)

     testm <- sparse.model.matrix(GRL~.-1, data = test)
     test_label <- test[,"GRL"]
     test_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(testm),label = test_label)
```

The response variable here is "GRL" and I am running the `test_label <- test[,"GRL"]`
The above code is getting executed but when I am trying to use it in `xgb.DMatrix`, I am encountering the following error:

> Error in setinfo.xgb.DMatrix(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) :
> The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data

I have partitioned the data into 70:30.

Comment: are there any `NA` values in your data?

Comment: I have imputed all the NA values.
So there are no NAs.

Comment: When you partioned the data, you should use ``replace == FALSE``, because when it's true you can have the same row in the train and test sample.

Comment: When using "replace = FALSE", the following error is showing up: -
    Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
    cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Comment: You can just run: 
``ind = sample(nrow(mission),nrow(mission)*0.7)
  train = mission[ind ,]
  test = mission[-ind ,]``

Comment: Thank you all for your help.
Your solutions have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test[,"GRL"]` returns a data.frame, and XGBoost needs the label to be a vector.

Just use `teste$GRL` or `test[["GRL"]]` instead. You also need to do the same for the training dataset

Comment: this will only be true if `test` is a tibble (which OP didn't show us).